# How to type in arguments in the middle of the code?

Tags: python, arguments

We can do this thing to type in any arguments:

```
from sys import argv
script, argument_1, argument_2 = argv
```

Is it possible to type in arguments in the middle of the code, not in the beginning?

I want to do smth the same:

```
print "La-la-la"
print "Any string"
# and here i want the program will take a file name as an argument to work with the file then
```

Comment: This question is completely undecipherable. I have no idea what you want to accomplish.

Comment: You can look at sys.argv whenever the heck you want to.

Comment: Stab into the dark: do you mean [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)?

Comment: deceze, maybe. Does it work in Python 2.7.10?

Comment: There's a selector on that manual page in the top left which lets you choose another Python version... see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html) a python class for command line parsing